# List all elements having order $7$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

> Let $G= \langle a \rangle$ be a cyclic group of order $35$. List all elements having order $7$.

I am unsure how to find these elements. I know that they will all be of the form $a^m$, but how can I determine the values of $m$ that will satisfy the question?

Comment: You need elements $a^m$ such that $(a^m)^7=1_G$, but $(a^m)^k\ne 1_G$ if $1\le k\le 6$. You know that $(a^m)^7=a^{7m}$, and you know that $a^n=1_G$ if and only if $n$ is a multiple of $35$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: What is $a^{35}$?  What is $(a^m)^n$?  When does $(a^m)^n = e$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The elements of $G$ can be written uniquely as $a^k$ for $0\leq k<35$. In order for $a^k$ to have order $7$, we need $a^{7k}=a^0$, so $7k$ has to reduce to $0$ modulo $35$. In other words, $k$ is a multiple of $5$. This gives $\{a^0,a^5,a^{10},a^{15},a^{20},a^{25},a^{30}\}$. However, the element $a^0$ has order 1 because it is the identity. Thus the elements of order $7$ are:
$$
\{a^5,a^{10},a^{15},a^{20},a^{25},a^{30}\}.
$$

Comment: I believe there is theorem stating that the use of ellipsis is justified if and only if the number of omitted items is at least $\gamma$ times the number of the displayed items, where $\gamma$ is a universal constant not less than $2/3$ :-)

Comment: What's the prove of this theorem? :)

Comment: Thank you! :). Just to make sure I understand the process correctly, let's now say that I want to find all elements of order $5$, then it would be $a^k$ where $k$ is all (positivity and nonzero) multiples of $7$ less than $35$, that is $\{a^7, a^{14}, a^{21}, a^{28} \}$ ?

Comment: Oh, it is obvious. It also has to do with some deep physical principles of least energy consumption. Why display four number and hide two, when you can hide four and display only two?

Comment: Yes. Also use brackes around two digit numbers like $\{14\}$ to get the exponents to render properly.

Answer (score 0):

By the Fundamental Theorem of Cyclic Groups, the only distinct subgroup of order d of a cyclic group <(a)> of order n, is <(a^(n/d))>, thus in this question, the only distinct subgroup of G is <(a^5)>. All subgroups of order 7 of G are <(a^(5*k))>, where 1<=k<=7, and g.c.d(k,7) =1. Thus, the subgroups are <(a^5)>, <(a^10)>, <(a^15)>, <(a^20)>, <(a^25)>, and <(a^30)>.